# how to write function for synchornization between two mysql databases using node-red

Tags: mysql, node-red

My plan is to store data in my local MySQL database and after a time interval it will update my  MySQL database remotely.
 The real problem is in our country net connection drops suddenly. So I want to first write to the local MySQL database and then it will update the real server. In any situation like internet connection dropped the script will work locally to gather data and retrieve data. When the internet connection comes back it will update the data to the real server. I want to protect against internet connection failures.

Nothing will update the real server in the mean time because the users are only in the office where the internet connection will drop. No one from the outside will able to update the database.

Comment: You will need to give us a little more to help us help you...

Comment: Try to make a replica, where your local database is the master and your remote database is the replica. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you don't do this with a function node.

The longer answer is that this should be 2 independent groups of nodes.

1 to store the required data in the local database.

1 with an inject node that runs at the interval you want to copy the data from the local DB to the remote DB that runs a query on the local instance that then inserts it into the remote DB. Pretty much all of this can be done with just the MySQL Database nodes and may be a split node to break up the results of the query into separate messages to feed into the node updating the remote DB.

Comment: how to write query with out using function node@hardillb